# Setting Trace Flags "Permanently" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, trace

We need to use [SQL Server Trace Flag 7646](http://sqldev.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/sql-server-2008-full-text-slowness/) to help mitigate some full text blocking, but I was dismayed to find that the trace flag "unset" itself, probably when the database server was rebooted.

I've used

```
DBCC TRACEON (7646, -1)
```

to set the trace flag and

```
DBCC TRACESTATUS
```

to show all trace flags, which told me that it *wasn't* set (after reboot, I guess). To set the trace flag permanently, I did this:

- went to SQL Server Configuration Manager
- viewed properties for SQL Server service
- visited the Advanced tab
- edited the Startup Parameters option

and added

```
;-T{tracenumber}
```

to the end, like so...

> -dD:\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf;-eD:\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG;-lD:\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf**;-T7646**

[image]

Is that correct? I am finding conflicting results on [the syntax for SQL Server Startup Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx).

Comment: FYI: There's an article here on how to set the startup parameters through T-SQL: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Automation/105511/

Comment: ps. Per the above, the following SQL will give you the relevant registry paths & current values for your instance: `select * from sys.dm_server_registry where value_name like 'SQLArg%'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yep, that'll about do it for you.  Using the -T{traceflag} startup parameter, that is.

Answer (score 11):

Something that I learned the hard way is that you have to have semicolons before each trace flag. For example, if you were enabling logging of deadlock info to file, your example would become...

```
-dD:\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf;-
eD:\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG;-
lD:\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.l
df;-T7646;-T3605;-T1204;-T1222
```

Spaces between trace flags cause the later flags to be ignored.